# RHEL Eclipse Failed to load the JNI shared library libjvm.so

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I installed a eclipse on the rhel.
After I configured the environment besides jdk,I had a problem.

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library libjvm.so
```

I searched the Internet for a solution to this problem. They said that I should modify a configuration file.

/etc/sysconfig/selinux

But I couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85304/what-is-the-safe-way-to-allow-java-7-to-run-on-selinux

A bug in the SELinux targeted policy causes the libjvm.so to be labeled incorrectly as type java_exec_t instead of textrel_shlib_t. So you can either disable selinux by editing /etc/selinux/config file

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html or giving the command setenforce 0

Thanks & Regards,
Alok